# Criar usuário e banco de dados MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, whm

**1 - É possível criar novo usuário e banco de dados MySQL via script PHP?**

**2 - No caso afirmativo, implicaria em algum risco de segurança tal ação?**

Objetivo: Tenho um sistema rodando (CMS próprio) onde o usuário faz praticamente tudo para se ativar no servidor, sendo que, este será alocado em um subdomínio em nosso servidor, portanto, a criação de um banco de dados para este novo usuário para este novo subdomínio precisaria ser de forma automatizada no momento do cadastro, o que hoje não ocorre e toda vez temos que criar novo usuário e banco de dados para um novo cadastro. Aceito sugestões se tiverem outros caminhos.

Detalhes: VPS rodando Linux / WHM(11.52.0) / cPanel(11.52.0.15) / MySQL(5.6.23) / PHP(5.5)

Answer (score 2):

1 - Sim se o usuário que o script php roda tiver "GRANT OPTION", ele poderá criar outros usuários e dar permissões, de nada até a sua permissão equivalente.

2 - Como se diz, a corrente é forte tanto quanto o elo mais fraco, depende da forma como seu php for montado. Fora isso tudo é perfeitamente possível da forma como você pretende.

Comment: Marcelo, sua resposta sanou parte da dúvida, porém em sua resposta não mencionou sobre criar banco de dados, e sim apenas criar usuários, sabe se com GRANT OPTION isso também é possível? Estou usando a própria classe do cPanel.

Answer (score -2):

Eu fiz assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" content="viewport">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Criando Banco de Dados...</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset form="formcreatedb">
            <legend>Criando Database</legend>
                <input name="nome" class="fcampo" required maxlength="50">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Criar Banco..." ><br><br>

        </fieldset>

    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $nome;";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Banco";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```